# What if there is no place for items and we give showAsAction="always"?

Tags: android, menu, android-resources

In the Menu layout file, we give `showAsAction` property with different defined values.

What if there is no place for items and we give `showAsAction="always"`?

If the item displays in the overflow menu what makes it different from `showAsAction="ifRoom"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no place for items and you give `showAsAction="always"`, `ActionBar` title starts to shrink, and creates more room for items:

[image]

If you use `showAsAction="ifRoom"` in this case, menu items move to the bottom of more button, **because there is no room for those menu items**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're giving each menu item to showAsAction="always", so every single menu item will be forced to show up in the action bar. This will cause other items in your action bar like the toolbar title and navigation button to have a smaller width. Because of this bug, Android Studio always suggested using `ifRoom` properties.

[All menu items with showAsAction="always"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDTqc.png)